# Kubernetes service not exposed when ClusterIp is set

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-service

I have the following YAML file -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mariadb
  name: mariadb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    name: mariadb
```

When this service is created, a ClusterIP is automatically set.
My stateful set 'mariadb' is exposed using this service.
But if I login to another pod on Kubernetes, I cannot ping this pod using

```
ping mariadb-0.mariadb.[namespace].svc.cluster.local
```

It also does not work if the ServiceType is set to 'NodePort'.

If I update the service to

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mariadb
  name: mariadb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    name: mariadb
```

When I login to another pod on Kubernetes, I can ping this pod using

```
ping mariadb-0.mariadb.[namespace].svc.cluster.local
```

Is there any reason why this internal url is not accessible when the ClusterIP is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is 'clusterIP: None'.

If clusterIP is not set, k8s will allocate one for the service automatically, also the kube-dns will set a domain name for the service, named mariadb.[namespace].svc.cluster.local, that's your first case.

While if clusterIP is set to 'None', that means k8s doesn't allocate a ip for the service, in this case, kube-dns will set a domain name for every endpoints that the service points to, in your second case, it's mariadb-0.mariadb.[namespace].svc.cluster.local.

Also you can set clusterIP to a ip address, in that case, it's the same as your first case.

That's why you can ping mariadb-0.mariadb.[namespace].svc.cluster.local in your second case, while can't in your first case.

Comment: I have a stateful set called mariadb, and a service (let's call it 'mariadb-service' to avoid confusion). How does my application use this mongodb stateful set?

So far, I've been setting clusterIP  to None and then used 
mariadb-0.mariadb-service.[namespace].svc.cluster.local
in another pod running my application.

My question is, How do I use it without setting the clusterIP to None.
Will something like this be accessible in another pod?
mariadb-service.[namespace].svc.cluster.local

Comment: Statefulset is supposed to use 'ClusterIP: None' to config service. In this way, you can either use mariadb-0.mariadb-service to access the pod, or you can use mariadb-service.[namespace]... to access one of the live pod.